# SQL - Using merge and counting the matched and non matched results

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, count

So if I were to use the following query I'd like to find out how many rows have been matched

```
MERGE (targetTable) AS t 
USING (sourceTable) AS s
ON t.ID = s.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  (some statements)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  (some statements)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  (some statements)
```

So I'd like to know the count for

- Matched
- Not matched by source
- Not matched by target

I know you can count the output, but if I recall correctly, the outputs only account for insert, update and delete.

Comment: what does this mean `Within some of my matched statements I might use both insert and update or neither`.

Comment: @TheGameiswar for example: When matched then Insert a into b update c  delete d. all within the same match. or possibly none within the same match.

Comment: There is only one statement possible within on match. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510625.aspx see `<merge_matched>`, `<merge_not_matched>`

Comment: Does this help: http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run something like this before merging:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID = s.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Matched],
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [NotMatchedByTarget],
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [NotMatchedBySource]
FROM targetTable AS t 
FULL OUTER JOIN sourceTable AS s
    ON t.ID = s.ID
```